# How to queue checkbox clicks before making http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a series of checkboxes and want to make an $http request when the user checks a checkbox. However, since the http request takes some time to complete and the user may want to check a few different boxes at a time, I want to delay sending the http request until the user has stopped checking boxes.

I have tried using $timeout to set a delay before sending the $http request, but this doesn't really queue the selections before sending.

```
var nodeList = [];

$scope.checkNode = function(checkedNode, sendRequestFn) {

    nodeList.push(checkedNode);

    $timeout(function() {
        sendRequestFn(nodeList);
        nodeList = []; // Sent the list, so reset this.
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear your timeout each time a button is clicked. With your implementation you are starting a new timeout each click.

```
var nodeList = [], waitBeforeRequest;

$scope.checkNode = function(checkedNode, sendRequestFn) {
  // if we are waiting, reset the timer
  if (waitBeforeRequest) $timeout.cancel(waitBeforeRequest);
  // wait for any more clicks before sending
  waitBeforeRequest = $timeout(function () {
    sendRequestFn(nodeList);
    nodeList = [];
  }, 500)

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly once I changed clearTimeout() to $timeout.cancel(). Thanks!

Comment: @RandyChung Sorry, I didn't realise that was an angularjs thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know when the user is done with the form and is ready to submit their checkbox changes. So, you should tie the http request to a submit button or button click of some kind, and the user will click on this button when done, triggering the update.

If you don't want to tie the http update to a button click, then I think tying the event to a timeout is your second best option, since there's no way to tell when a user is done with input.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is called a debounce function. You can write your own, but it is  available in the underscore library, that is usually fine to include in the page along with Angular. Example usage would be:

```
var nodeList = [];

var debouncedSend = _.debounce(function(sendRequestFn) { 
  sendRequestFn(nodeList);
  nodeList = [];
}, 500);

$scope.checkNode = function(checkedNode, sendRequestFn) {
  nodeList.push(checkedNode);
  debouncedSend(sendRequestFn);
};
```

The debouncedSend would be called outside of Angular, so you might need to wrap the function in $apply, as in:

```
var debouncedSend = _.debounce(function(sendRequestFn) { 
    $scope.$apply(function() {
    sendRequestFn(nodeList);
    nodeList = [];
  });
}, 500);
```